# How to display the value of a variable

Tags: vue.js

Gets data from collection:

```
const pageTitles = {
    homePage: 'Main'
...
  }
export default pageTitles
```

If I make all this way:

```
<div><span>{{pageTitles.homePage}}</span></div>
```

everything is ok.
But i need to show the value depending on route. I tried to make this:

```
pageTitle(){
      if (this.$route.path === '/'){        
        return pageTitles.homePage
      }
    }
```

and in div I have {{pageTitle}}, but it doesn't work. Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've omitted the `this` keyword before `pageTitles.homePage` in your computed property

```js
pageTitle(){
      if (this.$route.path === '/'){        
        return this.pageTitles.homePage
      }
    }
```

Comment: @yodyh, i can't understand: it doesn't work when i refresh page 1st time but if i change something in code (for example add ; or change name on property) without refreshing - it works.
console shows err: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'homePage')". but when i output it in console with console.log i see it.

Comment: likely you're doing some asychronous operation to fetch 'pageTitles', maybe from an API? Vue is trying to render this computed property immediately after component creation, but if pageTitles does not yet have a value yet (before the API fetch is complete), you'll get this error.  a simple solution is to ensure pageTitles has a value before accessing it.  change the if to `if (this.$route.path === '/' && this.pageTitles?.homePage)`

Answer (score 0):

It should work, Here you go **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pageTitles: {
        homePage: 'Main'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    pageTitle() {
        return this.pageTitles.homePage
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>{{ pageTitle }}</h2>
</div>
```